# FindClass returns null when .class is not in a default package

Tags: java, c, eclipse, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I've just looked at anyone else questions but it seems that nobody has the same problem of mine. I have a Java class HelloWorldHandler.java (in `org.eclipse.gemoc.testapplilauncher.handlers` package in `org.eclipse.gemoc.testapplilauncher` project) that launches another java application. Then I have a c file launcherC.c (in the same project but different directory) that is supposed to call the execute method in the java file, through JNI. Now, all my previous JNI applications worked, this one doesn't. The only difference is that HelloWorldHandler.java is not in the default package (so the .class is not directy in /bin) and there are multiple package imports (maybe something changes with the FindClass call (?)). 
I launch the c file with
`gcc  -fPIC -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux" -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64/jli/ -L/usr/lib/va-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -o launcherC launcherC.c -ljli -ljvm`

and

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/`

and there is no problem. But when I execute it, it doesn't do anything, without any Expections and errors. I checked and the FindClass returns NULL.

HelloWorldHandler.java

```
package org.eclipse.gemoc.testapplilauncher.handlers;


public class HelloWorldHandler {
    @Execute
    public static void execute() {

        ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();

        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        IFile ff = root.getFile(new Path("d/Test.launch"));


        ILaunchConfiguration res = manager.getLaunchConfiguration(ff);
        DebugUITools.launch(res, ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE);

    }
}
```

launcherC.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    long status;
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mid;

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/ezambon/Desktop/modeling/org/eclipse/gemoc/testAppliLauncher/bin/org/eclipse/gemoc/testapplilauncher/handlers";
    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    if (status != JNI_ERR)
    {
        cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "HelloWorldHandler");

        if(cls != 0) {
        //printf("asdfgh\n");
        mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "execute", "()V");

        if(mid !=0) {
             (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, mid);
        }
    }
    //printf("qwerty");
    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
    return 0;
  }
  else
    return -1;
}
```

All the suggestions are really welcome, I'm getting crazy. Thank you :)

Comment: That code in the handler will only run in an Eclipse plugin in a properly set up Eclipse. It will **not** run in a empty JVM such as you show here.

Comment: So, to make the JNI possible what should I do?

Comment: You can't run Eclipse plugin code like this. The closest is to create a 'headless' Eclipse RCP and run the executable.

Answer (score 1):

First problem you setup classpath wrong

Instead of

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/ezambon/Desktop/modeling/org/eclipse/gemoc/testAppliLauncher/bin/org/eclipse/gemoc/testapplilauncher/handlers";
```

you should have

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/ezambon/Desktop/modeling/org/eclipse/gemoc/testAppliLauncher";
```

and you should use full class name

```
cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "org.eclipse.gemoc.testapplilauncher.handlers.HelloWorldHandler");
```

But I suppose this is not all your problems.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. cls is still NULL. The only problem is in the path, because the rest of the code is the same of the other programs I made and all of them work.

Comment: use slashes (not periods) in qualified class name `org/eclipse/...`